# Parallelize reverse geocoding function over Python pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, multiprocessing

I have a Pandas dataframe. Inside 2 columns I have the latitude and the longitude of certain points. In another column, called city, I want to put the name of the city to which the latitude and longitude of the given row belongs.

I have sliced the latitude and longitude columns on the dataframe into a numpy array. Then I have used the multiprocessing library to create a small parallel map function which takes the numpy array, splits it, maps each function application for the given split to each one of the cores in my computer so that finally it can join the intermediate results.

However I have not been able to correctly do so. Since I'm somewhat new to Python I was wondering if there was a better (or even standard) way to do this.

My code is at follows:

```
def reverse_code( latitude, longitude ):
    g = geocoder.google([latitude, longitude], method="reverse")
    return g.city

def parallelize( data, func):
    data_split = np.array_split(np.array_split(data,2), partitions)
    pool = Pool(cores)
    data = pd.concat(pool.map(func, data_split))
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
    return data

cores = cpu_count()
partitions = cores
distritos = df[["latitud", "longitud"]].as_matrix

parallelize(distritos, reverse_code)
```

After I execute the code I get the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\jeptest\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\shape_base.py in array_split(ary, indices_or_sections, axis)
    457     try:
--> 458         Ntotal = ary.shape[axis]
    459     except AttributeError:

AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'shape'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-26-2af0d007a2f8> in <module>()
----> 1 parallelize(distritos, reverse_code)

<ipython-input-25-d2c492561bd2> in parallelize(data, func)
      1 def parallelize( data, func):
----> 2     data_split = np.array_split(np.array_split(data,2), partitions)
      3     pool = Pool(cores)
      4     data = pd.concat(pool.map(func, data_split))
      5     pool.close()

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\jeptest\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\shape_base.py in array_split(ary, indices_or_sections, axis)
    458         Ntotal = ary.shape[axis]
    459     except AttributeError:
--> 460         Ntotal = len(ary)
    461     try:
    462         # handle scalar case.

TypeError: object of type 'method' has no len()
```

Comment: `distritos = df[["latitud", "longitud"]].as_matrix` is assigning `distritos` to an instance method, rather than invoking the method. You need to invoke it with `()`.

Comment: You were right. I added the () and now the code is running. Any other suggestions you could recommend?